# Why can't I insert data to my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table using this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DimRegion]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [DimRegion]
Go
Create Table DimRegion

(RegionViewKey int NOT NULL identity Primary Key,                              
RegionView          varchar(10),
RegionViewCode      varchar(10),
ActiveYear              smallint,
SublocationString       varchar(7)NULL,
SubLocationCode     char(10)NOT NULL,
LocationCode            char(10)NULL,
RegionCode          char(10)NULL,
RegionGrpCode           char(10)NULL,
DivisionCode            char(10)NOT NULL,
DivisionGrpCode     char(10)NULL,
SubLocationDescription      char(50)NULL,
LocationDescription     char(50)NULL,
RegionDescription       char(50)NULL,
RegionGrpDescription        char(50)NULL,
DivisionDescription     char(50)NULL,
DivisionGrpDescription      char(50)NULL)
```

And I inserted data using this script

```
insert into DWResourceTask.dbo.DimRegion --(2013)

Select
'Region1' as RegionView,
'R1' as RegionViewCode,
'2013' as ActiveYear, 
sl.sublocationstring, 
sl.subLocationCode, 
l.locationcode,
r.regioncode,
rg.RegionGrpCode,  
d.DivisionCode, 
dg.DivisionGrpCode,
sl.SubLocationDescription, 
l.LocationDescription, 
r.regiondescription,
rg.RegionGrpDescription, 
d.divisionDescription, 
dg.DivisionGrpDescription
from SCSubLocation sl, 
SCLocation l, 
SCRegion r, 
SCRegionGrp rg,
SCDivision d,
SCDivisionGrp dg
where l.LocationCode = sl.LocationCode
and r.RegionCode = l.RegionCode
and r.RegionGrpCode = rg.RegionGrpCode
and d.divisioncode = rg.divisioncode
and d.divisiongrpcode = dg.divisiongrpcode
```

But when I created this script below where it would only insert new and latest data, it gives me an error such as

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>   Incorrect syntax near 'R1'.

Script:

```
insert into DWResourceTask.dbo.DimRegion --(2013)

Select
'Region1' as RegionView,
'R1' as RegionViewCode,
'2013' as ActiveYear, 
sl.sublocationstring, 
sl.subLocationCode, 
l.locationcode,
r.regioncode,
rg.RegionGrpCode,  
d.DivisionCode, 
dg.DivisionGrpCode,
sl.SubLocationDescription, 
l.LocationDescription, 
r.regiondescription,
rg.RegionGrpDescription, 
d.divisionDescription, 
dg.DivisionGrpDescription
from SCSubLocation sl, 
SCLocation l, 
SCRegion r, 
SCRegionGrp rg,
SCDivision d,
SCDivisionGrp dg
where l.LocationCode = sl.LocationCode
and r.RegionCode = l.RegionCode
and r.RegionGrpCode = rg.RegionGrpCode
and d.divisioncode = rg.divisioncode
and d.divisiongrpcode = dg.divisiongrpcode
and not exists(select * from DWResourceTask.dbo.DimRegion x
                  where(Region1=x.RegionView
                        R1=x.RegionViewCode
                        2013=x.ActiveYear 
                        sl.sublocationstring=x.sublocationstring
                        sl.subLocationCode=x.subLocationCode
                         l.locationcode=x.locationcode
                         r.regioncode=x.regioncode
                        rg.RegionGrpCode=x.RegionGrpCode
                         d.DivisionCode=x.DivisionCode
                        dg.DivisionGrpCode=x.DivisionGrpCode
                        sl.SubLocationDescription=x.SubLocationDescription
                         l.LocationDescription=x.LocationDescription 
                         r.regiondescription=x.regiondescription
                        rg.RegionGrpDescription=x.RegionGrpDescription
                         d.divisionDescription=x.divisionDescription 
                        dg.DivisionGrpDescription=x.DivisionGrpDescription)
                        )
```

How do I fix this script on top where it only inserts latest data

Comment: Tip: don't use `char(50)` - this will create a fixed-length column that will **always** be 50 characters long - no matter what you store inside it. Whatever you store will be padded to the fixed length with spaces. `Char(n)` is efficient for **short** strings, like codes (e.g. 3-digit ISO country codes etc.) - but it's **NOT** useful for longer string - use `varchar(50)` instead.

Comment: Hi marc_s,the data types that I used in creating the table were based from the existing source table in our current ERP system. Appreciate your thoughts about this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `WHERE` clause is missing the `AND`s between parts of the condition:

```
...
where(Region1=x.RegionView
     AND  R1=x.RegionViewCode
     AND  2013=x.ActiveYear 
     AND  sl.sublocationstring=x.sublocationstring
     AND  sl.subLocationCode=x.subLocationCode
     AND  l.locationcode=x.locationcode
     AND  r.regioncode=x.regioncode
     AND  rg.RegionGrpCode=x.RegionGrpCode
     AND   d.DivisionCode=x.DivisionCode
     AND  dg.DivisionGrpCode=x.DivisionGrpCode
     AND  sl.SubLocationDescription=x.SubLocationDescription
     AND   l.LocationDescription=x.LocationDescription 
     AND   r.regiondescription=x.regiondescription
     AND  rg.RegionGrpDescription=x.RegionGrpDescription
     AND   d.divisionDescription=x.divisionDescription 
     AND  dg.DivisionGrpDescription=x.DivisionGrpDescription)
 )
```

Comment: Thank you dasblinkenlight. I didnt notice that I was missing those ANDs. Maybe I could use some breakfast before doing this.